# Seaborn clustermap show only axis labels for genes with high z-value

Tags: python, seaborn

I am generating heatmaps for expression matrices containing 1000-15000 genes and I'm only interested in the subset of highly expressed genes. Is there a way to show labels only for the ones with high z-values?

Right now I'm just setting a very small font for the x-axis, but that's not a scalable solution.

Example code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
from functools import reduce

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(200, 4), columns=['cell_1', 'cell_2', 'cell_3', 'cell_4',])

idx=([f'Gene {i}' for i in range(0, 200)])

df['gene'] = idx
df.set_index('gene', inplace=True)
g = sns.clustermap(df.transpose(), method='average', metric='correlation', z_score=0, figsize=(15,15), xticklabels=True)
g.ax_heatmap.set_xticklabels(g.ax_heatmap.get_xmajorticklabels(), fontsize = 5)
```

[Example heatmap with too many gene labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0j3e.png)

I'd like to get a more readable x-axis, where only labels for genes with high z-values are shown.

Thank you!

Comment: seaborn (matplotlib behind the scene) has primitives for accessing the x, y labels, you may be able to modify the generated plot (before actual draw) by filtering the shown ticks or tick labels depending on associated value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty attempt.
You can make it cleaner or with better perfs, but you get the idea.

It might be better to have a look [at this matplotlib doc link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html) it explains how to make custom annotations to heatmap and might be of use.

You also may consider working on your dataframe first and only plot relevant data (dataframe "filtering")

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
from functools import reduce

total_genes = 50
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(total_genes, 4), columns=['cell_1', 'cell_2', 'cell_3', 'cell_4',])

idx=([f'Gene {i}' for i in range(0, total_genes)])

df['gene'] = idx
df.set_index('gene', inplace=True)
transposed = df.transpose()
# print(transposed)
g = sns.clustermap(transposed, method='average', metric='correlation', z_score=0, figsize=(15,15), xticklabels=True)
g.ax_heatmap.set_xticklabels(g.ax_heatmap.get_xmajorticklabels())#, fontsize = 5)

# tmp = g.ax_heatmap.get_xaxis()

threshold = 1.2
x_labels_ticks = g.ax_heatmap.get_xticklabels()

total_genes_above_threshold = 0
for i, xtickdata in enumerate(x_labels_ticks):
    gene = xtickdata._text
    if transposed[gene].max() >= threshold:
        # print("gene {} has at least one value > {}".format(xtickdata, threshold))
        # print(transposed[gene])
        # print("#########")
        total_genes_above_threshold = total_genes_above_threshold + 1
    else:
        xtickdata._text = ''

print("total_genes_above_threshold {}".format(total_genes_above_threshold))

# re set the tick labels with the modified list
g.ax_heatmap.set_xticklabels(x_labels_ticks)
```